# Parse a log file using regex to pull out failed logins by date

Tags: linux, perl

New to perl and could use some help wrapping my head around regex and how they can be used.  I have a file names auth.log that contains a bunch of logins both successful and failed.  I have what I hope is correct code to read in the file and read through line by line, now I just need to figure out how to pull out the failed ones and print them to the screen by date. Below is an example on what a failed login looks like, and my code to read in the file.  I know regex will look for a match on the word failed, I just cant get the syntax.

Sep 14 07:23:59 icarus sshd[10393]: Failed password for someUser from 137.190.220.15 port 64704 ssh2

Sep 14 07:24:04 icarus sshd[10393]: Failed password for someUser from from 137.190.220.15 port 64704 ssh2

Sep 14 07:30:17 icarus sshd[10523]: Accepted password for someUser from 137.190.19.13 port 58506 ssh2

I believe I am getting closer now, trying to initiate a counting variable in it just to spit out how many Failed passwords were in the file, when I run this script I get a WHOLE ton of numbers that eventually just ends with the prompt again, which I believe means it is at least still running through the entire auth.log, or it would have no end?  Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$count = 0;

open (MYFILE, 'auth.log');
while (my $line = <MYFILE>){
if ($line =~ /Failed password/){
$count++;
}
print $count;
#print "$line\n" if $line =~ /Failed password/; 
#this was a test to make sure it was was getting all the Failed password attempts in              the auth.log.
}
close (MYFILE);
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: No need to `chomp` if you plan on printing a newline anyways.  And more common syntax is `while( <MYFILE> )`.

Comment: Lesson 1: The language is spelled "Perl"

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $current_date = '';

open ( my $file, 'auth.log') or die 'Could not open auth.log';

while ( <$file> ) {
    next unless my ( $user_id ) = m/\Q: Failed password for \E(\w+)/;
    my ( $date ) = m/^((?:J[au]n|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \s+ \d+)/x;
    if ( $date ne $current_date ) {
        $current_date = $date;
        %failures_for = ();
        print "$current_date\n--- --\n";
    }
    my $time = ++$failures_for{$user_id};
    print "$user_id #$time: $_";
}
print "\n";
close $file;
```

I also added an idea of saving something like a failure count for  a user, reset each day.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Swiss Army Knife approach.

To see all the failures:

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/'
```

To see all the failures for September:

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/' | perl -ne 'print if /^Sep/'
```

To see all the failures between 'Sep 07 00:00:00' and 'Oct 18 22:20:00'

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/' | perl -ane '$date = @F[0..2]; print if q(Sep 07 00:00:00) <= $date && $date <= q(Oct 18 22:20:00)'
```

To count them:

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/' | perl -ane '$date = @F[0..2]; print if q(Sep 07 00:00:00) <= $date && $date <= q(Oct 18 22:20:00)' | wc -l
```

To find them for SomeRandomUser

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/' | perl -ne 'print if / for SomeRandomUser /'
```

My thesis is that learning this style of Perl can allow you to quickly do custom extractions from your log files in ways it is hard to anticipate in advance. Once you have them working you can turn them into a more robust program later, if that adds value to your company.

Ps. My favorite is how do you extract lines 123 thru 456 of a file? You can use a combination of head and tail like:

```
cat file | tail -n +123 | head -334
```

But that requires two commands some subtraction and a possible fencepost error. Instead I memorized:

```
cat file | perl -ne 'print if 123 .. 456'
```

To print from 123 to the end of file:

```
cat file | perl -ne 'print if 123 .. eof'
```

This can be useful in your case - rather than trying to remember how I use Perl's -a switch and and the semi-magical '$date = @F[1..3]', you could use your editor to see that the log entries for the dates you are interested in are on lines 1234 thru 2345 and then do

```
cat auth.log | perl -ne 'print if 1234 .. 2345' | perl -ne 'print if /Failed password/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(MYFILE, '<auth.log');
while (my $line = <MYFILE>) {
  print "$line\n" if $line =~ /Failed password/;
}
close(MYFILE);
```

If you wanted to get fancy and pull out just the user/IPs .. you can do this

```
print "$1 User: $2, IP: $3\n" if $line =~ m/^([A-Za-z]{3}\s+[0-9]{,2}\s+[0-9:]+).*Failed password for ([^ ]+) from ([^ ]+)/;
```

This technique is called using back references in regular expressions, where in Perl, `$N` (where N is some number) corresponds to the string enclosed in each set of parenthesis, from left to right. So `$1` corresponds to the date .. `$2` corresponds to the data (any non-space character, in this case) following `Failed password for` .. or in all the logs you gave it would contain `someUser`. Similarly `$3` will contain the IP, since it is the third set of parenthesis, capturing any non-space character following the string `from`.